# RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [1024] at entry 0 and [1728] at entry 181

Tags: python

Since I haven't used any platform like stack overflow before (and also I don't have a coding background), so there may be some shortcomings in the statement of my question. I apologize for that and will be happy to improve my question based on your advice.

We come across a problem in running a script in our git repo. In this program, the **input data** is in the form of **keypoint embeddings**, and our goal is to perform **Data Augmentation**.
Our Git repo is [here](https://github.com/DFKI-SignLanguage/slt.git)

Whenever we run the script keypoint_rotation.py, [which can be accessed here](https://github.com/DFKI-SignLanguage/slt/blob/augmentation-preprocessing/signjoey/preprocessing/keypoint_rotation.py), it gives an error at line 55 as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\areeb\Downloads\SignLanguage_DataAugmentation\slt\signjoey\preprocessing\keypoint_rotation.py", line 172, in <module>
     rotated_dataset = rotate_dataset(DATA_CFG, ROTATION_CFG_DEFAULT)
   File "C:\Users\areeb\Downloads\SignLanguage_DataAugmentation\slt\signjoey\preprocessing\keypoint_rotation.py", line 109, in rotate_dataset
     for example in iter(raw_dataset):
   File "C:\Areeb Files\PythonLang\lib\site-packages\torchtext\data\iterator.py", line 156, in __iter__
     yield Batch(minibatch, self.dataset, self.device)
   File "C:\Areeb Files\PythonLang\lib\site-packages\torchtext\data\batch.py", line 34, in __init__   
     setattr(self, name, field.process(batch, device=device))
   File "C:\Areeb Files\PythonLang\lib\site-packages\torchtext\data\field.py", line 237, in process   
     tensor = self.numericalize(padded, device=device)
   File "C:\Areeb Files\PythonLang\lib\site-packages\torchtext\data\field.py", line 357, in numericalize
     arr = self.postprocessing(arr, None)
   File "C:\Users\areeb\Downloads\SignLanguage_DataAugmentation\slt\signjoey\preprocessing\keypoint_rotation.py", line 55, in stack_features
     return torch.stack([torch.stack(ft, dim=0) for ft in features], dim=0)
   File "C:\Users\areeb\Downloads\SignLanguage_DataAugmentation\slt\signjoey\preprocessing\keypoint_rotation.py", line 55, in <listcomp>
     return torch.stack([torch.stack(ft, dim=0) for ft in features], dim=0)
 RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [1024] at entry 0 and [1728] at entry 181
```

The torch.stack function requires all tensors to be of same size, but here we have either of size 1024 or 1728. It seems that this error arises due to unequal number of zero paddings maybe, but I am not sure how can I solve it?
Any help in this regard will highly be appreciated.

I tried to debug, not sure problem is whether in line 60 or line 96.